# Java - Two Circles overlap or inside

Tags: java

I have a problem on my homework, and I am having trouble getting the last part to work.  What am I doing wrong here? It will not print "Circle 2 overlaps Circle 1." or "Circle 2 does not overlap Circle 1."  The first two cases do print.  Here is the question:

Write a program (TwoCircles.java) that prompts the user to enter the center coordinates and radii of two circles and determines the geometrical relationship between the two and print one of the following messages accordingly:
1.  Circle 1 is inside Circle 2.
2.  Circle 2 is inside Circle 1.
3.  Circle 2 overlaps Circle 1.
4.  Circle 2 does not overlap Circle 1.

Here is what i have so far for my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TwoCircles {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Circle 1 center x-, y-coordinates, and radius: ");
    double X1 = input.nextDouble();
    double Y1 = input.nextDouble();
    double radius1 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter Circle 2 center x-, y-coordinates, and radius: ");
    double X2 = input.nextDouble();
    double Y2 = input.nextDouble();
    double radius2 = input.nextDouble();    

    double distance = Math.pow((X1 - X2) * (X1 - X2) + (Y1 - Y2) * (Y1 - Y2), 0.5);

    if (radius2 >= radius1){
        if (distance <= (radius2 - radius1))
            System.out.println("Circle 1 is inside Circle 2.");}
    else if (radius1 >= radius2){
        if (distance <= (radius1 - radius2))
            System.out.println("Circle 2 is inside Circle 1.");}
    else if (distance > (radius1 + radius2)){
        System.out.println("Circle 2 does not overlap Circle 1.");}
    else {
        System.out.println("Circle 2 overlaps Circle 1.");}
    }
}
```

Any guidance appreciated

Comment: which is your code the 1st one or the 2nd one ?

Comment: What do you mean - "This code prints two output for the first two."  The first two what?  What input are you providing and what does it print?

Comment: The output is coming twice because you are using if conditions without else if... So, the control is matching two if conditions : one for radius and other for distance. Use the if .. else if block properly. You will get correct output.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TwoCircles {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Circle 1 center x-, y-coordinates, and radius: ");
    double X1 = input.nextDouble();
    double Y1 = input.nextDouble();
    double radius1 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter Circle 2 center x-, y-coordinates, and radius: ");
    double X2 = input.nextDouble();
    double Y2 = input.nextDouble();
    double radius2 = input.nextDouble();    
    double distance = Math.pow((X1 - X2) * (X1 - X2) + (Y1 - Y2) * (Y1 - Y2), 0.5);
    if (radius2 >= radius1 && distance <= (radius2 - radius1)){
        System.out.println("Circle 1 is inside Circle 2.");
    }
    else if (radius1 >= radius2 && distance <= (radius1 - radius2) ) {
        System.out.println("Circle 2 is inside Circle 1.");
    }
    else if (distance > (radius1 + radius2)){
        System.out.println("Circle 2 does not overlap Circle 1.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Circle 2 overlaps Circle 1.");}
    }
}
```

The problem with the code which you are using is that either of the first two conditions:

```
if(radius1>=radius2)
```

or

```
else if(radius1<=radius2)
```

will always be true and hence the code will never reach the third or fourth condition. The correct way to achieve what you are trying to do is to merge all the conditions together which i have done in the code presented above. 
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You probably "lost" yourself in that if-else statements.

First of all, I would recommend to write it with ALL the braces to understand correctly, what exactly is happening there :

```
    if (radius2 >= radius1) {
        if (distance <= (radius2 - radius1)) {
            System.out.println("Circle 1 is inside Circle 2.");
        }
    } else if (radius1 >= radius2) {
        if (distance <= (radius1 - radius2)) {
            System.out.println("Circle 2 is inside Circle 1.");
        }
    } else if (distance > (radius1 + radius2)) {
        System.out.println("Circle 2 does not overlap Circle 1.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Circle 2 overlaps Circle 1.");
    }
```

As you can see, you say "if radius2 is equal or greater than radius1" do something and if not and if "radius1 is greater or equal radius2" do something else.

If you think about it, there is no possibility which is neither first or second condition. So the last two statements are logically unreachable.